# API Permission Status not granted warning in Azure AD Application API Permission

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In the below image as you could see I'm getting the warning,
"**Not granted for SKCET Corporation Private Limited**",
what should I do to remove it ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Global Administrator would need to go to that page and click Grant admin consent button.

You can see the documentation on admin consent here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent

Comment: Can you add this link as well to your answer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure** that if you're the only one or just opened the account that you are an admin on Microsoft 365.

1. You will need to add a TXT record in your DNS settings (F.e. Route53 - AWS)
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/misc/become-the-admin?view=o365-worldwide

Once that is verified you will automatically be a global administrator and then you will have access to all admin features.

2. Then just click on the small hard to see in grey here:
   [image]